# Unwanted space between negative number and footnote marker

Tags: tables, footnotes, siunitx, threeparttable

I have managed to produce a table that looks like I imagined it to, so all is well there. The only problem I am having is with my footnote markers. I am using threeparttable and siunitx, and I want to mark statistically significant numbers with an asterisk. I have done this, but for some reason, negative numbers have a space between the number and the asterisk, but the positive numbers don't. How do I either get rid of the space on the negative numbers, or add it to the positive numbers (so that it is the same for negative and positive numbers).

I am quite new to LaTeX, and very much self taught, so do forgive me if I don't understand anything suggested.

I have added a simplified version of my table code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx,booktabs,threeparttable}
\robustify\bfseries
\robustify\tnote

\begin{document}
    \sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{test table}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}[b]
            \begin{tabular}{ccSS}
                \toprule
                Period & Event & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Single} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Multi}\\
                \midrule
                1901--2011 & El Ni\~{n}o &-2.69\tnote{*} & -1.03\\
                & La Ni\~{n}a & 2.98 & 8.48\tnote{*}\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item[*] statistically significant at the 95\% level
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `table-align-text-post=false` to your options. BTW `%` also ought to be treated as a unit ie use `\SI{95}{\%}` or `\SI{95}{\percent}`